how to use startActivityForResult or registerForActivityResult method in AccessibilityService?
I want to run an activity from inside the AccessibilityService and wait for the result. But it does not know the registerForActivityResult or startActivityForResult methods.
What solution do you suggest?
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someMethod = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    if (data == null)
                        return;
                    // do somethind();
                }
            });

and in button click listener
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
            someMethod.launch(myIntent);

I searched all the posts but couldn't find anything.

What is the use case for this? Why would an accessibility service need to launch and wait for an activity?

@dominicoder
To receive data from the user and use it in methods
